# CATCH unit testing for C++ compare std::array

Tags: c++, unit-testing, stdvector, stdarray, catch-unit-test

I like to use [catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) for my c++ unit tests.
My goal is to compare `std::array` and `std::vector`.  I created the this failing example.

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Vector") {
    std::vector<double> direction = {0.1, 0.3, 0.4};
    std::vector<double> false_direction = {0.1, 0.0, 0.4};
    REQUIRE(direction == false_direction);
}

TEST_CASE("Array") {
    std::array<double, 3> direction = {0.1, 0.3, 0.4};
    std::array<double, 3> false_direction = {0.1, 0.0, 0.4};
    REQUIRE(direction == false_direction);
}
```

The output of this test is for the check of `std::vector`

REQUIRE( direction == false_direction )
with expansion:
  **{ 0.1, 0.3, 0.4 } == { 0.1, 0.0, 0.4 }**

and for `std::array`

REQUIRE( direction == false_direction )
with expansion:
  **{?} == {?}**

What can I do to display the actual and expected value? I like to have the very same display in a violated `REQUIRE` condition for `std::array` as for `std::vector`.

I use the latest version of catch (v1.10.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally this is a question of how a type is stringified, and for that there is always the [documentation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tostring.md).

The abridged version is that there is a simple algorithm

1. Check for specialization of `Catch::StringMaker` for given type. If exists, use it.
2. Check for `operator<<` overload for given type. If exists, use it.
3. Use "{?}".

Until recently, Catch provided a specialization for `std::vector` out of the box, but not for `std::array`, because `std::array` was part of C++11 and generally less used. [Since version 2.1.0](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/releases/tag/v2.1.0) Catch instead checks whether the type provides a container-like interface, specifically, responds to `begin(T)` and `end(T)`. This provides an automatic stringification for many different types, including `std::vector`, `std::array`, but also static arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check Catch's source code to see how exactly they implement the `REQUIRE` clause, and why it won't work but `vector` does.
But here is a workaround:

```
#define COMPARE_ARRAYS(lhs, rhs) compareArrays(Catch::getResultCapture().getCurrentTestName(), __LINE__, lhs, rhs)

template < typename T, size_t N >
void compareArrays(const std::string & test, unsigned line, std::array<T, N> lhs, std::array<T, N> rhs) {
  std::vector<T> lv(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
  std::vector<T> rv(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
  INFO("Test case [" << test << "] failed at line " << line); // Reported only if REQUIRE fails
  REQUIRE(lv == rv);
}

TEST_CASE("Array") {
    std::array<double, 3> direction = {0.1, 0.3, 0.4};

    std::array<double, 3> true_direction = {0.1, 0.3, 0.4};
    COMPARE_ARRAYS(direction, true_direction);

    std::array<double, 3> false_direction = {0.1, 0.0, 0.4};
    COMPARE_ARRAYS(direction, false_direction);
}
```

Comment: This would work for sure, but it will decrease the readability of the test code.

Comment: @schorsch312, improved solution to be much cleaner, reusable and without compromising on test output information

Answer (score 1):

I traced the problem down the the `toString` method within the catch header. It is missing the overload for `std::array`, `std::vector` has already be instantiated.  I will commit this change to the catch project.

```
// already exists in the catch header
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
std::string toString( std::vector<T,Allocator> const& v ) {
    return Detail::rangeToString( v.begin(), v.end() );
}

// my modification in the catch header
template<typename T, std::size_t _Nm>
std::string toString( std::array<T, _Nm> const& v ) {
    return Detail::rangeToString( v.begin(), v.end() );
}
```